# iball i342MV  Microphone Low recording volume

Tags: windows-7, microphone

I have got some problems with the `microphone recording volume in my Windows 7 machine`. The mic is new and is working well in Win Xp and other OS. When I connected to my Win7 machine, the recorded sound seems to be very low and something like whispering. 
I have tried with the option in the Sound panel from the System Tray icon (`Right click Volume icon >> Recording Devices`)

I'm using `Dell Studio 1555` and there is an inbuilt mic and I have disabled this also. Is there anything to do to get the mic recording volume increased?

Comment: Microphone make and model will help get a better answer.

Comment: @DaveM Mic is iball i342MV